# create a summary slide of each row of the dataframe through a loop

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, presentation, officer

I am trying to create a powerpoint presentation with a mix of plots and text. I have the following example data:

```
data <- structure(list(School_ID = c("J-56124", "T-65451", "D-78544", "TBD", 
"B-78664"), Release_Date = structure(c(18659, 19024, 19052, 19052, 
19079), class = "Date"), Value = c("11 M", "15 M", "9 M", "3 M", "5 M"), 
Type = c("a", "b", "c", "TBD", "TBD")), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I have the following text with references to the data frame `data` that I want to plot:

```
text_1 <- paste0("A: just some text \n",
"some other text \n",
"Type: ", data$Type[1], "\n",
"comments \n", 
"Place: LA \n",
"Value: ", paste0('$',formatC(data$Value[1], big.mark=',', format = 'f'))[1], "\n",
"Release Date: ", data$Release_Date[1], "\n",
"School ID: ", data$School_ID[1], "\n",
"more lengthy text to finish the slide")
```

I first define a font style:

```
fp_normal <- fp_text(color = "black", font.size = 12, font.family = "calibri")
```

Then I create the slides and print the presentation as:

```
my_pres <- read_pptx("my_template4.pptx") %>%
  add_slide(., layout = "Title and Content", master = "Office Theme") %>%
  ph_with(., value = "my title", location = ph_location_type(type = "title")) %>%
  ph_with(., value = "my subtitle", location = ph_location_type(type = "subTitle")) %>%
  ph_with(., value = fpar(ftext(text_1, fp_normal)), location = ph_location(left = 0.3, top = 1.2, width = 4, height = 3)) 

print(my_pres, target = "my_file.pptx")
```

I want to print a new slide for each row of the dataframe `df` with the same content as shown in `text_1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to wrap your code to create the character string inside a custom helper function then use a `for` loop to loop over the rows your dataset to add a slide for each row like so:

```
library(officer)
library(dplyr)

text_1 <- function(x) {
  paste0(
    "A: just some text \n",
    "some other text \n",
    "Type: ", x$Type[1], "\n",
    "comments \n",
    "Place: LA \n",
    "Value: ", paste0("$", formatC(x$Value[1], big.mark = ",", format = "f"))[1], "\n",
    "Release Date: ", x$Release_Date[1], "\n",
    "School ID: ", x$School_ID[1], "\n",
    "more lengthy text to finish the slide"
  )
}

my_pres <- read_pptx()

for (i in seq(nrow(data))) {
  my_pres <- my_pres %>%
    add_slide(., layout = "Title and Content", master = "Office Theme") %>%
    ph_with(., value = "my title", location = ph_location_type(type = "title")) %>%
    #ph_with(., value = "my subtitle", location = ph_location_type(type = "subTitle")) %>%
    ph_with(., value = fpar(ftext(text_1(data[i,]), fp_normal)), location = ph_location(left = 0.3, top = 1.2, width = 4, height = 3))  
}

print(my_pres, target = "my_file.pptx")
```

[image]